# RDS to local DB restoration error

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, amazon-rds

Has anyone facing this issue before ?

```
mysql -u root -pxxxx public_wordpress_v2 < public_wordpress_v2.sql 

ERROR 1214 (HY000) at line 566: The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes
```

What is this error about and how to resolve it ?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/the-used-table-type-doesnt-support-fulltext-indexes).  Have you tried changing your table type to MyISAM?

Comment: What's you MySQL version? InnoDB tables support FULLTEXT indexes only from MySQL 5.6 up.

Comment: @vhu MySQL version is 5.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled with Mysql 5.6 it worked ! Thanks